# Cefsharp process user ID passing

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, chromium, cefsharp

I want to launch the cefsharp.browsersubprocess using a specific user id. How do I initialise cefsettings to incorporate the same ? Is there a way to do it ? It always picks up the windows user id, but I want to give a specific user id.

Comment: There's no configuration option for this, it's unlikely the browser would function correctly.

Comment: Oh ok. Is there any other workaround to achieve the same ? My application is launched using a specific user id and cefsharp browser exe is launched using the windows id. There is a conflict and the functionalities are not working as expected. Hence the ask.

Comment: How are you specifying the user I'd of the main application?

Comment: It is picked up from the Registry/Active Directory.

Comment: Doesn't really answer my question. How are you setting the user id?

Comment: This is a windows application. When the application is launched, we read the Registry and set the user id in a global object, that is used across the application. Whenever we need user id anywhere in the application, this global object will be used. We have embedded chromium browser within our application and we have a scenario where the application user id differs from the windows user id. The browser is launched using windows user id. So authentication fails in few layers since the windows id will not have the same level of access as the application user Id.

Comment: What exactly is a global object in this context? Child processes are launched with the user Id of the parent process. This is the default behaviour of Windows,  there's no configuration options for how the chromium child, even if there was it's unlikely the browser would function correctly. Running your process as the desired user is likely your only option.

Comment: You can try impersonate your desired user for your main application thread.